# Converting two lists to type : List[List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]]

Tags: list, scala

Have two Lists :

```
 val list1 : List[List[(String, String)]] = List(List("1" -> "a" , "1" -> "b"))
                                                  //> list1  : List[List[(String, String)]] = List(List((1,a), (1,b)))
 val list2 : List[List[(String, String)]] = List(List("2" -> "a" , "2" -> "b"))
                                                  //> list2  : List[List[(String, String)]] = List(List((2,a), (2,b)))
 //Expecting
 val toConvert = List(List(Map("1" -> "a" , "2" -> "b"), Map("1" -> "b" , "2" -> "a")))
```

Attempting to convert these lists to type :

```
 List[List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]] = Lis
                                                  //| t(List(Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b), Map(1 -> b, 2 -> a)))
```

Using this code :

```
val ll = list1.zip(list2).map(m => List(m._1.toMap , m._2.toMap))
```

But Map entries are missing :

```
 List[List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]] = List(List(
                                                  //| Map(1 -> b), Map(2 -> b)))
```

How to convert list1,list2 to type `List[List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]]` which includes values : `(List(Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b), Map(1 -> b, 2 -> a)))` ?

Update :

Logic of : `Map("1" -> "a" , "2" -> "b")`

Combine each List using the zip functions :

```
  val p1 : List[(List[(String, String)], List[(String, String)])] = list1.zip(list2);
```

Convert each element of thenewly created List to a Map and then add to a newly created List :

```
val p2 = p1.map(m => List(m._1.toMap , m._2.toMap))
```

Comment: What is the logic behind getting the first map as: `Map("1" -> "a" , "2" -> "b")`?

Comment: @Filippo please see update, is this what you mean ? There is no real meaning behind the data, im just playing with the collection methods as a learning exercise.

Comment: any comment about the answer posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to convert `list1` and `list2` to type `List[List[Map[...`

Starting from the type `List[List[(String, String)]]` we would like to get to the type `List[List[Map[String, String]]]`.

### Inner Type

The inner type we want is `Map[String, String]`. As I asked in the comments, I don't fully understand the expected logic to construct this `Map` so I am assuming you want to create a `Map[String, String]` from a list of tuples `List[(String, String)]`.

When creating the `Map` using `.toMap`, the `key-value` elements with the same `key` will get overwritten as we can see clearly from the `b += x` in its implementation:

```
  def toMap[T, U](implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)): immutable.Map[T, U] = {
    val b = immutable.Map.newBuilder[T, U]
    for (x <- self)
      b += x
    b.result()
  }
```

(source [TraversableOnce.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L312))

**So the logic we use to create `List[(String, String)]` will determine the generated `Map[String, String]`**.

### Outer List of List

> Combine each List using the zip functions

```
type A = List[(String, String)]
val list12: List[(A, A)] = list1 zip list2
```

Zipping `list1` and `list2` gives us a list of tuples but the type we want is actually a list of list of tuple: `List[List[(A, A)]]`

In your example you are getting that type mapping to a list `m => List(...)`. That is the key part. Let me split that in 2 parts to make it clearer:

```
list12.map(m => List(m._1 , m._2)).map(_.map(_.toMap))
```

Let's extract that into a separate function:

```
def keyPart: ((A, A)) => List[A] = { case (l1, l2) => List(l1, l2) }
val resultNotExpected = list12.map(keyPart).map(_.map(_.toMap))
```

The result is of course the same of the one in your question:

```
resultNotExpected == List(List(Map("1" -> "b"), Map("2" -> "b")))
```

### The "keyPart"

In your question you mentioned the expected result as:

```
List(List(Map("1" -> "a", "2" -> "b"), Map("1" -> "b", "2" -> "a")))
```

I still don't understand the logic you have in mind for the now extracted `keyPart` function so I would give you mine... over-complex of course:

```
  val resultExpected = list12.map { case (l1, l2) => List(l1, l2) }
    .map(_.map(_.zipWithIndex)).map(_.zipWithIndex)
    .map(_.map { case (l, i) => l.map { case ((k, v), j) => (k, v, i, j) } }).map(_.flatten)
    .map(_.groupBy { case (k, v, i, j) => i == j }).map(_.values.toList)
    .map(_.map(_.map { case (k, v, _, _) => k -> v }.sorted).sortBy(_.head._2))
    .map(_.map(_.toMap))

scala> resultExpected == List(List(Map("1" -> "a", "2" -> "b"), Map("1" -> "b", "2" -> "a")))
Boolean = true
```

Perhaps you know better the logic to be implemented in `keyPart`.